# How to make a CDF document with dynamic content?

Tags: cdf-format

I would like to create a CDF document that uses dynamic content. The example code is:

```
fun=x^2-1;
InputField[Dynamic[fun]]
```

And what I get is $Aborted instead of interactive document. How to make a useful document?

EDIT:

What I am really trying to do is to make a CDF document in which the given function is plotted. Initially the function is x^2-1, but the user should be able do input any function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually doing

```
CDFDeploy["test.cdf", Manipulate[
  Plot[fun, {x, 0, 10}],
  {fun, x^2 - 1}], Method -> "Standalone"]
```

you will see that the FreeCDF will not let you do what you want, i.e., some interaction like you get in normal Mathematica by:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[fun, {x, 0, 10}],
 {fun, x^2 - 1}]
```

Check out the differences between FreeCDF and Enterprise CDF
http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/licensing-options.html

The important little detail is "arbitary input fields": this is just not enabled in FreeCDF.
So, it looks like you have to get Mathematica Enterprise in order to produce EnterpriseCDF's.

Oh, and don't forget to "Contact the CDF Team" : http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/contact-us/

Comment: Well... that is a pity, but I don't think that I will spend 5,6k pounds just to let my students make interactive plots :p So the question is: what can I do with Standard edition?

Comment: So... If I made an application in Mathematica, it would be useful only if someone had CDF-pro or if I made those CDF files using Enterprise edition of Mathematica. Am I right?

Comment: I cannot find any official information for the situation in Mathematica 9. Maybe Andre or someone else officially from WRI can answer... It seems unclear right now.

Answer (score 6):

This may do what you want:

```
InputField[Dynamic[x, (x = #^2 - 1) &]]
```

Comment: That looks nice, but only for functions like x^2-1. But what if I would like to put there any function.

Comment: `(x = f[#])&` is also OK, assuming that you have defined the 1-argument function f elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very good. I just wasn't aware of limitations of CDF files :(